# How force unload library in C++ (Dev C++ compiler)?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I saw a Delphi (Object Pascal) code that force unloads any module (dll) that is loaded inside my software. Then with base in this code, I'm wanting and needing of something similar now in C++ (Dev C++).

Someone can help me please?

Here is Delphi code that I saw:

```
procedure ForceRemove(const ModuleName: string);
var
  hMod: HMODULE;
begin
  hMod := GetModuleHandle(PChar(ModuleName));
  if hMod=0 then 
    exit;
  repeat
  until not FreeLibrary(hMod);
end;
```

Comment: This would be platform specific. On Linux you would use [libdl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen). Not sure about other platforms.

Comment: @Galik, I'm needing of a similar code for Microsoft Windows system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions

```
HMODULE GetModuleHandle(LPCTSTR modulename)
BOOL FreeLibrary(HMODULE)
```

are functions of the Windows API. It can be called from any language that supports programming against the Windows API, as C++

Only recommendation: Remove the loop (the repeat until not ...) in your sample above. It should be replaced by code that interprets the return value of the call to FreeLibrary, documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx

The DLL will be unloaded from memory (that is to say, the address space of the executing process), as soon as its per-process reference count goes zero; you cannot force unloading a DLL globally by repeatedly executing FreeLibrary() if another process still holds a reference.

EDIT: included a direct translation of OP's sample into a C++ snippet:

```
void ForceRemove(LPCTSTR ModuleName)
{
    HMODULE hMod;
    hMod = ::GetModuleHandle(ModuleName);
    if(hMod==0) 
        return;
    /* DISCLAIMER potentially infinite loop
     * not advisable in production code,
     * included by request of the OP to
     * match his original */
    while(::FreeLibrary(hMod));
}
```

Comment: I'm needing force unload because have a injector that have a "infinite loop" that always loads a dll for my software. Then this way above seems be more efficient. I still have that put this "unload" function also in a infinite loop, because is this way that works in Delphi. If exists another way for do this, I don't know.

Comment: I see. it's not "clean", it might work though. I only see risking an infinite loop because we'd have to assume that the FreeLibrary() function reliably returns FALSE after a finite number of calls... in practice, it might do so... not advisable in production code I'd say

Comment: So you could edit your answer, leaving a similar code as this Delphi example above please? I'm not very intimate with C++ for this.

Comment: this line based on Delphi code above, I think that could be `while "not" (::FreeLibrary(hMod));`, or I'm wrong?

Comment: hmm... repeat until waits for a true condition. original code has "repeat until not". while breaks on false condition. docs say, "If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero." so it is correct like this since 0 evaluates to FALSE